# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema con mi Array en C#?

Tags: c#, array

tengo un inconveniente. No tengo mucho conocimiento, pero estoy tratando de hacer un programa que sume cada columna y fila de un array, pero cuando termino de digitar los valores en consola, aparece este error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] datos = new int[2, 3];
        int SumaFilas = 0, SumaCol = 0;
        Program bda = new Program();
        bda.Lectura(datos);           
        bda.Math(datos, SumaFilas, SumaCol);          

    }

    public void Lectura(int[,] datos)
    {
        for(int f = 0; f < 2; f++)
        {
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Digite el valor para {0},{1}", f + 1, c + 1);
                datos[f, c] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
    public void Math(int[,] datos, int SumaFilas, int SumaCol)
    {

        for (int f = 0; f < datos.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < datos.GetLength(1); c++)
            {

                SumaFilas += datos[f, c];
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Fila " + f + "=" + SumaFilas);
        }

        for(int c = 0; c < datos.GetLength(0); c++)
        {
            for(int f = 0; f < datos.GetLength(1); f++)
            {
                SumaCol += datos[f, c];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Columna"  + c + "=" + SumaCol);
        }

    }

}
```

}

Obtengo el resultado de la suma, pero no encuentro la manera de evitar que este error aparezca, podrían ayudarme? gracias de antemano

Comment: Agrega el codigo completo y no una imagen.  Estas trabajando con una matriz pero no la veo declarada. El error en si es porque dice que estas accediendo a una posicion de la matriz mayor a la que tenes declarada.

Answer (score 0):

En el for donde te genera el error tienes invertidas las filas con las columnas, por eso se te cae.

En la línea del error, remplaza por lo siguiente:

```
SumaCol+= datos[c, f] ;
```